# GridSearchCV: get attributes of a model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use `GridSearchCV` to fit SVM, and I want to know the number of support vectors for **all** the fitted models. For now I can only access this SVM's attribute for the best model.

Toy example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
clf = SVC()
params = {'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1]}
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, cv=2, param_grid=params, return_train_score=True)
search.fit(X, y);
```

with the number of support vectors for the best model:

```
search.best_estimator_.n_support_
```

How to get the `n_support_` for all models? Just as we get train/test error separately for each parameter `C`.

Comment: Not sure it's possible; you can do it for `C` because it is the tuned parameter, which is not the case for `n_support_`...

Comment: @desertnaut actually, during the last hour I got an idea: make a custom scorer as `scorer(clf, X, y)` and append the parameters of a model to some global list while loss is evaluated. I just don't think that it is the most elegant solution possible...

Comment: Maybe, but sounds worth trying if you definitely want this `n_support_` info.